# Permssions for ftp user directories - Arch, nginx, vsftp, multiple users

Tags: nginx, permissions, http, vsftpd, arch-linux

I've set up chroot jails where the users are restricted to their home directories, though I'm not quite sure how to properly set up permissions for my users to be able to ftp upload http content, with myself, vsftp, and nginx still being able to access the content.

Comment: Hello, at a very minimum, would you share what platform are you working on? OS, distro, administration webgui, etc?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear enough, Arch Linux. No web gui.